# Flutter - Support build of multiple BuildTypes

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I've created 3 buildTypes at my android project:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            resValue "string", "app_name", "AppName"
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "AppName - DEV"
        }
        staging {
            initWith release
            matchingFallbacks = ['release']
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
    }
```

I would like to assemble my staging build type, so I ran "flutter build apk --staging", but flutter can't find that option:

```
Could not find an option named "staging".
```

Seems that Flutter build apk command "**flutter build apk**" supports only 3 types : debug, profile, release; and in case of using custom buildType - there's no support for that.

Is it possible to build an apk of custom BuildType?

Comment: I believe you can only use --flavor and specify flavors :/ (see the output of `flutter help build apk` for more info).

Comment: @MartinMarconcini thanks, so it means flutter doesn't support multiple buildTypes?

Comment: Don't quote me on that, my experience with flutter is rather limited but after seeing your question I spent a little bit researching and haven't found a way to do it, perhaps a more experienced flutter dev can chime in :) (update: have you read https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration) ? It mentions that you can change the "build variant" in the AS project... perhaps that does it?

Comment: This is what I noticed: https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration -> yes it's talking about `release` but the screenshot shows various build variants.

Comment: Yeah, i couldn't find enough info regarding that as well. The screenshot shows that they use 3 buildType i.e debug, release and profile, and also a flavour called "dynamic". I guess the only solution right now is to rename "staging" to "profile". That being said, there's still no support for more than 3 buildTypes.

Comment: Bear in mind that "profile" is a special one (like dev/release) what is optimized for profiling... so I'm not sure if that's a good idea (to use) but unless someone can find a way, I don't see any other way round (short of using Flavors for everything, which is also a PITA).

Answer (score 4):

I ended up using productFlavors:

```
flavorDimensions 'app'


productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension "app"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "AppName - DEV"
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
        staging {
            dimension "app"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "AppName - DEV"
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
        prod {
            dimension "app"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "AppName"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use Android's own Gradle build tasks instead of using Flutter commands.

1. `cd android/`
2. `./gradlew app:build`

Then after a succesfull build you should be able to find an apk for each buildType in `build/app/outputs/apk/`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution to this problem，open `$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle` find `project.android.buildTypes`

add your buildtypes to this block, then back to your android project,invalidata cache/restart.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was starting a build type custom.

This code (see "preprod") worked for me (Flutter 3.0.4):
command line: `flutter run --flavor preprod --release`

```
signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file('../keystores/debug.keystore')
        storePassword 'android'
        keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
        keyPassword 'android'
    }
    releasetest {
        storeFile file('../keystores/releaseTest-keystore.jks')
        storePassword 'releaseTest'
        keyAlias 'releaseTest'
        keyPassword 'releaseTest'
    }
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

flavorDimensions "flavor-type"

productFlavors {
    dev {
        dimension "flavor-type"
        applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
    }
    preprod {
        dimension "flavor-type"
        buildTypes.release.signingConfig signingConfigs.releasetest
    }
    prod {
        dimension "flavor-type"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't actually *need* it to be a build type, you could use Flutter's supports for defining properties in Gradle like this:

```
flutter run --release --android-project-arg staging=1
```

Then in Gradle, you can detect this property and change things depending on it:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        resValue "string", "app_name", "AppName"

        if (project.hasProperty("staging")) {
            matchingFallbacks = ["release"]
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
    }
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "AppName - DEV"
    }
}
```

Adding this argument to your launch configuration is also easy, in VS Code for example just add this to `.vscode/launch.json`:

```
"args": ["--android-project-arg", "staging=1"]
```

I was having a similar issue that I tried to solve with build types or flavors, but Flutter's support on this is very limiting at the moment. I ended up using a property like this.